# ASP.net - Name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    //page load event
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //displaying current date on the label
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

and in *site.master* I have:

```
<header>
<h2>Two Column Layout.</h2>
<br />
<div id="displayDate">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate" />
</div>
```

Here is the code from the top of the *.master* file as requested:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MillerDylanTwoColumn.site" %>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error CS0103  The name 'lblDate' does not exist in the current context

Can anyone show me where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you please share code for Master page directive located at the top of your .master file?

Comment: Make sure your Masterpage design file has the `lblDate` property registered - it binds the label on the .MasterPage file to the codebehind class.  Also make sure your codebehind file is registered properly in the top of the MasterPage html file.

Comment: Try removing the label, save, close visual studio and then reopen it and add it back

Comment: Here is the code from the top of the .master file: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MillerDylanTwoColumn.site" %>

Answer (score 1):

Doublecheck so the file `Site.master.designer.cs` is included in the project. Otherwise `Site.master.cs` wont be able to find the components.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Label lblDate = (Label) Master.FindControl("lblDate");

        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

**Update:**

Then add this namespace to your partial:

`using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`

Comment: Hey. I tried that now I get: 
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Label' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Label' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi, so now I have this error:
Error CS0116 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods using this code:
     {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var lbl = sender as Label;
        lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
      }
   }

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, it would be easier just init the text while the label load event instead of finds the control instance in page load.

```
protected void lblDate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = sender as Label;
    lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

By the way, if you need time, not only date. You may need timer or something similar to update the label.

Comment: Hey, I still get errors with these updates: 
Error CS0116 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods 
Error CS0103 The name 'Master' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I used the one posted above, then it just gives me this error:
Error CS0116 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: CS0116 usually is because you accidentally locate a field or method outside of the class

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer here as I can't comment. But do you need to change the label value later on or is it just a one time load? If it is a one time deal you could just do, if you need to make it live you could put it in an update panel with a refresh timer.
`<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>' />`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a bunch of these error messages when building my project, for no reason.

Somehow the designer.cs files were not being refreshed.

I fixed by re-saving the files and rebuilding again.

Also one of my designer.cs files was pointing to the wrong UpdatePanel.

Changed from:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.UpdatePanel MainUpdatePanel;
```

To:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel MainUpdatePanel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is a really old issue, but it really waste my days.

Finally last programmer for my company project made several copy files for the page that issue occures.

Such as

"filename - copy.aspx",

"filename - copy.aspx.cs",

"copy - filename.aspx"

and "copy - filename.aspx.cs".

Just delete all of them then problem solved.